# Is it possible to find a statistical difference?

Tags: statistical-significance, mean

I'm measuring the strength of two properties for 15 subjects. Let's call the strength of the two properties A and B.

The variable A varies with time and I have 12 measurement per minute for 15 minutes per subject = 180 measurements for every subject. Those are numerical continuous values and normally distributed.

The variable B is a constant, and we only have one value for B for every subject (B represents a value that represents all the 15 minutes of the experiment for each subject). Those are numerical continuous values as well.

In my statistical analysis I'm calculating a ratio between the mean of A and B for every subject by simply dividing the mean of A with B. Thus I end up with one ratio per subject.

Now for the million dollars question: Can I somehow calculate the statistical difference between the subjects in terms of those ratios? I want to find out if there's a significant difference between the ratio of subject 1, 2, 3..15.

I'm open to any solutions or workarounds.

PS. All values are independent.

Comment: If $B$ is non-zero for each subject, then you can define $C=\frac A B$ with $12$ observations of $C$ for each subject and then make your question about the means of the $C$s for each subject

Comment: I've been thinking about doing that, but it just seemed a bit artificial. What test would I use to do this?